# Hive - DynamoDB export not work in europe?

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, hadoop, hive, amazon-dynamodb

There appears a problem when using Hive & DynamoDB in the EU region.

My test case is:

- Hive version - 2.3.0 eu-central-1
- Dynamodb table - test_input eu-central-1

Hive script:

```
    CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE raw_data (id STRING, parent_id STRING, value STRING)
    STORED BY "org.apache.hadoop.hive.dynamodb.DynamoDBStorageHandler"
    TBLPROPERTIES (
      "dynamodb.table.name" = "test_input",
      "dynamodb.region"="eu-central-1",
      "dynamodb.column.mapping" = "id:id,value:value,parent_id:parent_id"
    );
```

After run script I get:

*FAILED: Execution Error, return code 1 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.DDLTask. java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not lookup table test_input in DynamoDB.*

According to old tread https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=326618 , I tried many steps to solve it. 
After adding: 
SET dynamodb.endpoint=dynamodb.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com.
Again the same error.

I tried also add:

```
<property>
    <name>dynamodb.endpoint</name>
    <value>dynamodb.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com</value>
    <description>DynamoDB endpoint</description>
</property>
```

To /etc/hive/conf/hive-default.xml and /etc/hive/conf/hive-site.xml. Still have the same result.
I searched internet to find solution without success :(

Any ideas how to solve it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved by adding to /etc/hadoop/conf/core-site.xml:

```
<property>
    <name>fs.s3.awsAccessKeyId</name>
    <value>Key</value>
</property>
<property>
    <name>fs.s3.awsSecretAccessKey</name>
    <value>Secret</value>
</property>
```

Only this is required, EMR use this account instead roles.

Comment: I tried several things, but this is what worked for me. Thanks

Comment: What is the key and secret here ?